# How to generate a random string in MongoDB that is not in a collection?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I know how to generate such a random string in MySQL:

```
select random_strings.random_string as pin
from (
  select lpad(conv(floor(rand() * pow(36, 6)), 10, 36), 6, 0) as random_string
) as random_strings
where random_strings.random_string not in (
  select pin 
  from my_table
  where pin is not null
)
limit 1;
```

but I need to do so using MongoDB. How can I achieve that ?